# Mean value theorem and second derivative is zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function from class $C_2$ (which means it has a second derivative and the second derivative is continuous). Suppose that the segment connecting the points $(0, f(0))$ and $(1, f(1))$, the graph of $f$ intersects at a point $(a, f(a))$ with $0 < a < 1$. Show that there is an $x​​ \in [0,1]$ so that $f''(x) = 0$.

So I know I can use the mean value theorem to prove this. I tried to apply the MVT to $[0, a]$ and $[a,1]$. Suppose there is a $c_1 \in [0, a]$ and a $c_2 \in [a, 1]$

$$f'(c_1) = \frac{f(a) - f(0)}{a}$$
$$f'(c_2) = \frac{f(1) - f(a)}{1-a)} $$

But how do I prove that the second derivative is zero?
And is this the right way to solve this?

Comment: By segment do you mean a line segment?

Comment: Yes, I mean line segment ;)

Comment: You don't need continuity of second  derivative (the accepted answer does not use this hypotheses).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method is right.Note that if (a,f(a)) lies on segment joining (0,f(0)) and (1,f(1)) then by using property of slopes

$\frac{f(a)-f(0)}{1-0}=\frac{f(1)-f(a)}{1-a}$

or $f'(c_1)=f'(c_2)$

thus by rolles theorem there exists some $x$ such that $f''(x)=0$